# Нормализация кросс-корреляции

Tags: fft, c++

Доброго времени суток! Я пытаюсь написать программу для поиска шаблона в сигнале. Сигнал переодический, квазистационарный. Задача - получить адекватный коэффициент корреляции(КК). 
Перед основными вычислениями произвожу удаление среднего из выборок:

```
x = x - mean(x)
```

Для расчета КК использую подход на основе БПФ:

```
corr(x, y) = F'( F(x) * conj(F(y)) ),
```

где F() - прямое БПФ, F'() - обратное БПФ, conj() - получение комплексно сопряженного. Для того чтобы работало БПФ использую дополнение нулями исходных массивов x и y до степени 2 следующим образом

```
[000000xxxxxxx000]
[yyyyyyy000000000]
```

После выполнения процедуры corr() получаю кросс-корреляционную функцию, максимум которой вроде как является искомым КК, а позиция максимума соответствует сдвигу шаблона в сигнале. Однако, чтобы получить КК полученный максимум надо нормировать(чтобы получить значение в диапазоне от -1 до 1)
Вопрос собственно в том как правильно нормировать полученный максимум?

P.S. если будет необходимо могу привести исходный код.

Comment: Ох. Первый вопрос на моей памяти о преобразовании сигналов. Удачи!

Comment: Спасибо) Буду пытаться дальше)

Comment: Есть линейный коэффициент корреляции (Он же коэффициент Пирсона), можно его попробовать.

Comment: Куда, в какой диапазон вы его пытаетесь нормировать? С какой целью?
Насколько я понимаю, его надо привести к диапазону (-1,1)? Вы это хотите сделать?

Comment: Да!! Именно это! Можете подсказать как это реализовать?

Comment: 1) http://bourabai.kz/signals/ts02.htm
2) для несмещенной функции (с вычтенным средним) для нормирования надо ее поделить на среднеквадратическое отклонение. А вот как его посчитать... это надо смотреть...

Comment: Так а чем плох мой ответ то? коэффициент Пирсона это нормированная величина [-1 ; 1]

Comment: Все бы хорошо, но коэффициент Пирсона - он ведь для дискретных выборок, а тут у нас непрерывные функции.
Нам надо считать cтандартное отклонение =  sqrt(integral(-беск,беск)function(x)^2 * g(f(x)) dx)
где самое интересное - это g(f(x)) - плотность вероятности функции f(x). Вот как ее из исходных данных вытащить - не знаю.

Comment: В вопросе написано что он удаляет среднее из выборок, или я не так понял?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хм.  IronVbif, а ведь Вы похоже правы. Система дискретна.Можно либо применить критерий Пирсона к начальной задаче (и сразу получить результат).
А также  можно получить нормированную корреляцию путем деления
полученной функции на корень квадратный из дисперсии:
normcov=f(x)/(sqrt((sum((f(x) - mean(x))^2)/n)).
Похоже, это и есть ответ.

Comment: Огромное всем спасибо!!! Все заработало! Отдельное спасибо bear11 и IronVbif! Я попробовал нормировать на кв. корень из дисперсии и на норму векторов: результат одинаковый) Поскольку я удалил среднее из выборок) Впрочем разницы в скорости и точности почти нет))